# How to extend Devise SessionsController#create when using allow_unconfirmed_access?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my Rails project I am using Devise and I've turned on allow_unconfirmed_access in the devise initializer like this:

`config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 1.day`

This works great. If a user has not confirmed their account via the confirmation email, they can still login for 24 hours. After this, if they attempt to login, Devise handles it and gives a flash message and returns a 401, disallowing the login.

I want to be able to hook into this and add a step to auto-resend the confirmation email but I can't figure out for the life of me where to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the Devise::SessionsController to add this behavior:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_action :resend_confirmation_email_if_unsent, on: :create

  def resend_confirmation_email
    @user = resource  # resource is a devise controller helper method

    unless @user.active_for_authentication?
      @user.resend_confirmation_instructions  # Resets token

      # Or, if you don't want to reset the tokn
      # @user.send_confirmation_instructions
    end
    # ....
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I might as well answer it as I was dealing with the same situation.

Anthony E's answer is almost correct, but it missed the fact that `resource` is not defined before the create action starts, thus resource is `nil` at that moment. My solution was this:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_action :resend_confirmation_email_if_needed, on: :create

  def resend_confirmation_email_if_needed
    @user = resource_class.find_by_email(resource_params[:email])
    unless @user.nil? || @user.active_for_authentication?
      @user.resend_confirmation_instructions
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if it's a good idea to retrieve the user this way. It would be much easier if `super do |resource|` worked for this, but it only runs upon successful login, which is not the case.

Hope this helps!